# To display specific data related of current user to get rendered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

Hi I want to ask how to get data of booking for current user logged in,

the schema model seperated into 2 files (userModels and bookingModels)

userModels

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const validator = require('validator');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please tell us your name!'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide your email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email'],
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false,
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      validator: function (el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Passwords are not the same!',
    },
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    select: false,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

booking model

```
const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    corporate: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Must belong to a User'],
    },
      thumbnail: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Must have a link'],
      validate: [validator.isURL, 'Please provide a valid URL address'],
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

bookingSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'corporate',
    select: 'name',
  });
  next();
});
const Booking = mongoose.model('Booking', bookingSchema);

module.exports = Booking;
```

and this is the service/handler to render to front-end pug

```
const Booking = require('../models/bookingModels');
const User = require('./../models/userModels');

exports.getMyBooking = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const bookings = await Booking.find(req.user.id, {
    corporate: req.body.corporate,
    thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail,
  });
  res.status(200).render('package', {
    title: 'My Package',

    bookings,
  });
});
```

my PUG file more or less

```
extends base
   block content
     main.main
         form.form.form-user-data
            .form__group
              label.form__label(for='corporate') Name
              input#name.form__input(type='text', value=`${booking.corporate}`, required, name='name')
            .form__group.ma-bt-md
              label.form__label(for='thumbnail') Detail
              input#email.form__input(type='text', value=`${booking.thumbnail}`, required, name='thumbnail')
```

No problem with other router I think but it keep showing in the front end page console as "Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object"

Not so sure whats wrong again with the code as this is my first project.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The find() function expects the first argument as an object and you are passing a string.

See [mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

And since you have User refererence in your Booking model, to filter based on user you can try like this:

```
exports.getMyBooking = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const bookings = await Booking.find({
    corporate: req.user.id
  });
  res.status(200).render("package", {
    title: "My Package",
    bookings,
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. But actually its in different schema model file. I updated it in my question. 
I just actually tried this one too:
const bookings = await Booking.findById({ corporate: { $in: req.user.id } });
but it doesnt work either with findById

Comment: You need to filter bookings based on the login user right? If yes this will work const bookings = await Booking.find({    corporate: req.user.id}); . Just make sure you have value in req.user.id. Also in your view file, you need to write value=`${booking.corporate.name}` to get the name from the user object

Comment: I think thats right the code your suggest is correct.as I see when I console.log(bookings) showed the correct data. but when it comes to the rendering it still got this error `33| .form__group 34| label.form__label(for='corporate') Name > 35| input#name.form__input(type='text', value=`${booking.corporate.name}`, required, name='corporate') 36| .form__group.ma-bt-md 37| label.form__label(for='thumbnail') Detail 38| input#email.form__input(type='text', value=`${booking.thumbnail}`, required, name='thumbnail') Cannot read property undefined` i tried rendering with other model schema,and it works